# Android Plot Bar Graph with X-Axis and Y-Axis

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, achartengine, android-4.4-kitkat

I am searching for android bar chart/Graph with x and y-axis where y axis would be values `.. In chart, I just need to display 4 values only. I found out many samples but not the simple one with 4 values to display in bar chart. Can anyone suggest me example of simple bar chart..with x,y axis . 
I am searching similar to the below image

[image: bar chart]
<sub>(source: [wekaleamstudios.co.uk](http://www.wekaleamstudios.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/barchart-lattice1.jpeg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Try This!
   MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type;
import org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.renderer.SimpleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int SERIES_NR = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = getTruitonBarRenderer();
        myChartSettings(renderer);
        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, getTruitonBarDataset(), renderer, Type.DEFAULT);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getTruitonBarDataset() {
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        final int nr = 4;
        Random r = new Random();
        ArrayList<String> legendTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
        legendTitles.add("Sales");
        legendTitles.add("Expenses");
        for (int i = 0; i < SERIES_NR; i++) {
            CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(legendTitles.get(i));
            for (int k = 0; k < nr; k++) {
                series.add(100 + r.nextInt() % 100);
            }
            dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
        }
        return dataset;
    }

    public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getTruitonBarRenderer() {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 30, 40, 15, 0 });
        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        return renderer;
    }

    private void myChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer) {
        renderer.setChartTitle("BarChart Example");
        renderer.setXAxisMin(0.5);
        renderer.setXAxisMax(10.5);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(210);
        renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "2010");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "2011");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(3, "2012");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(4, "2013");
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
        renderer.setXTitle("Years");
        renderer.setYTitle("Performance");
        renderer.setShowGrid(true);
        renderer.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
        renderer.setXLabels(0); // sets the number of integer labels to appear
    }

}
```

Add This line to your Manifest file:

```
 <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" />
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help.. this works .. but problem is I added this code in one of the activity of my app... but this seems to open some differnt app .. as when i press the back button it open the activity hello page ... then on again back press moves back